# Rails nested has_one: cannot delete existing record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-one

I'm trying to update nested question_output attributes in a 'question' model. A question has_one question_output. *If* there are no existing question_outputs in the database, everything works fine. But if the record already has a question_output, I get the following when trying to update:

> Failed to remove the existing associated question_output. The record
>   failed to save when after its foreign key was set to nil.

I would have thought the allow_destroy would take care of that, but alas - no joy. Admittedly I haven't used has_one much before. But if anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, I'd be appreciative. Relevant code below:

The form:

```
= form_for [@question.project, @question], :as => :question, :url => admin_project_question_path(@question.project, @question) do |f|
  = render '/shared/form_errors', :model => @question
  = f.fields_for :question_output_attributes do |qo|
    .field
      = qo.label :question_type
      = qo.select :question_type, QuestionOutput::QUESTION_TYPES
    .field
      = qo.label :client_format
      = qo.select :client_format, QuestionOutput::CLIENT_FORMATS
    .field
      = qo.label :required
      = qo.check_box :required
    .field
      = qo.label :min_input, 'Length'
      = qo.text_field :min_length
      = qo.text_field :max_length
    = f.submit 'Save Question Formatting'
```

Question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :question_output
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_output, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

QuestionOutput model:

```
 class QuestionOutput < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :question
 end
```

Questions controller:

```
class Admin::QuestionsController < ApplicationController

 def show
   @question = Question.find(params[:id])
   @question.question_output ||= @question.build_question_output
 end 

 def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
      flash[:notice] = t('models.update.success', :model => "Question")
      redirect_to admin_project_question_path(@question.project, @question)
    else
      flash[:alert] = t('models.update.failure', :model => "Question")
      redirect_to admin_project_question_path(@question.project, @question)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In your question model change the has_one line to:

```
has_one :question_output, :dependent => :destroy
```

the `:allow_destroy => true` on the `accepts_nested_attributes` allows you to delete a question_output from within the question form via the `_destroy=1` HTML attribute.

The `:dependent => :destroy` deletes the question_output when you delete the question.  **Or in your case** deletes the question_output when it is replaced by a new one.

Comment: hi, i'm in the situation like this, i have a user has_one address when i try to update my user it gives me the same error as @PlankTon, if i use :dependent => :destroy , each time i update user informations it destroy association and create a new one with different id ! there is a method to juste use exesting association without destroy then create it

Comment: @medBo was about to answer your question but see it got answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984093/cant-update-my-nested-model-form-for-has-one-association)

Answer (score 1):

Every time create a new record is some kind of overhead.
You simply have to include hidden field with record id and it will be just updated instead of destroying

```
= qo.hidden_field :id
```

Comment: dont you think this is a huge security risk?