# Can't update my nested model form for has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to create a nested model form for the has_one association. (i'm using Rails 4)

In my user, and adress model i have the following :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :address
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

end
```

my user controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    .
    .
    .
    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
      @user.build_address if @user.address.nil?
    end 

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update(params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, address_attributes: [:street]))
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated successfully"
        sign_in @user
        redirect_to @user
      else
         flash.now[:error] = "Cannot updating your profile"
         render 'edit'
      end
    end
end
```

finally in my view i have :

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object
  %div
    = f.label :user_name, "User name"
    = f.text_field :user_name
    = f.fields_for :address do |add|
      = addd.label :street
      = d.text_field :street
    = f.submit "Update"
```

When i try to fill street filed for the first time it works, but when i try to **update** i get the error : `Failed to remove the existing associated address. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil`

any idea where is the error ? thank's

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in your controller `UsersController`, in the `update` method, add the `address: :id` to the address permitted attributes. Like this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, address_attributes: [:id, :street]))
```

Comment: woow it works thank you, this is what i search :D but can you explains more what was the cause of my error here

Comment: can you explains me more why i should add id to my address_attributes please

Comment: @medBo i don't know why you have to include the :id to the nested attributes you have to update. it is not especially documented and i had exactly the same issue a couple of months ago, struggling over a week-end before finding the solution. maybe a more senior/expert Rails developer can help. happy to have been helpful ;-)

Comment: merci beaucoup :D i see that you are french ;) thank you for help

Comment: It's not safe. Better to use `update_only: true` option, as `stoodfarback` explained.

Comment: stoodfarback's answer re `update_only: true` should be the accepted answer here

Answer (score 36):

There is an option to make it do a partial update if the record already exists:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for(:address, update_only: true)
```

Documented here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: good catch i will try it later, before it needs to add the id of the nested attributes, now documentation is more clear about this point thank you @micaeked

Comment: man, i tried with all answers related with devise and nested forms, you're the only person with a clear, simple answer and the best, IT WORKED!!! thank you a lot, i tried hard (14 hours) until make that!

Answer (score 0):

This error usually indicates that there is an existing record for the `has_one` relationship. In other words, this particular `user` object already has an `address` record associated with it. This could happen while testing the form in the browser.

In this case, it seems like Rails is trying to create a new address record, and it has to do with how your `edit` action is written.

Try this:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  @address = user.address || @user.build_address
end
```

Comment: but i try to update information not to create a new record !!

Comment: why you add [at]address instance variable ? in my code i don't need any variable [at]address !!

Comment: there is some way to say if user.address already exist then @user.build_address(existing_adress)  ???

Comment: This says `assign address to either user.address, or, if that's nil, assign to a new address instance (@user.build_address)`

Comment: solution is add :id to strong parameters, like @d34n5 says