# Modify Rails has_one relationship to UPDATE instead of DELETE then INSERT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models with a `has_one` relationship:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :location, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, allow_destroy: true

  ...
  default_scope {joins(:location).includes(:location)}
  ...

  # has a properties 'name' and 'url'

end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true

  # has a property named 'address'

end
```

I noticed that changes to the `name` or `url` properties of the `Entity` model via the form will cause the associated `Location` record to be DELETEd then INSERTed.  This is a less-than-desirable action.

** edit **

In further testing, I noticed that these settings have no bearing on the SQL strategy:

- `polymorphic` joins
- `allow_destroy: true`
- `dependent: :destroy` - other than leaving an orphaned record in the `Locations` table
- `default_scope`

Questions:

1. Why is a change to an `Entity` property causing an change to the `Location` model?
2. Why is this performing a `DELETE`/`INSERT`, rather than an `UPDATE`?

Comment: For your first question,it is what the `allow_destroy` do when it set to `true`.You will find it in this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 5):

Solution: add `update_only: true` to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, update_only: true
```

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20727728/134367
- [API documentation for `accepts_nested_attributes_for(*attr_names)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the id in your nested attributes will performe an `UPDATE`, rather than a `DELETE/INSERT`.

```
entity.update(location_attributes: { id: entity.location.id, ... })
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**