# Rails: Accept optional nested Image; allow to add later if nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, nested-forms, nested-attributes, option-type

I have a simple Article model associated with an Image model. The relationship is currently one-to-one (might change later but is fine for now).

Everything works fine when I create an Article from scratch and add an Image to it. Here's the catch: I would like the Image to be optional at creation, but also I would retain the option to *add* an Image at a later stage.

However, I am not sure how to handle that through the edit action. I have tried this:

```
  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.image.nil?
      @article.image = Image.new
    end
    render 'articles/edit'
  end
```

... which results in:

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved in Admin::ArticlesController#edit**

**Failed to save the new associated image.**

The form currently looks like this:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :image do |image| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= image.label :image, "Article image" %><br/>
      <%= image_tag(@article.image.path.thumb.url) %>
      <%= image.file_field :path %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= image.label :caption %>
      <%= image.text_field :caption, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= image.label :credits %>
      <%= image.text_field :credits, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

How can I accomplish optional nested images that can be added through the edit form later on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplicity of Rails never ceases to amaze me. Here's how I solved it by adding one line (`@image = ...`):

```
  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @image = @article.image || @article.build_image
    render 'articles/edit'
  end
```

... inspired by [Can't update my nested model form for has_one association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984093/cant-update-my-nested-model-form-for-has-one-association)