# RoR - The record failed to save when after its foreign key was set to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Problem:

```
LocationsController request to edit should load the requested location
Failure/Error: @location.image = @image
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved:
       Failed to remove the existing associated image. 
The record failed to save when after its foreign key was set to nil.

LocationsController request to edit should be successfull
Failure/Error: @location.image = @image
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved:
       Failed to remove the existing associated image. 
The record failed to save when after its foreign key was set to nil.
```

Part of the Controller:

```
def new
 @location = Location.new
end

def create
  @location = Location.new(params[:location])
  @location.owner_id = current_user.id
  @address = Address.new(params[:address])
  @location.image = Image.new(params[:image])
  responds_to_parent do
    if @location.save && @location.image.update_from_uploaded_data(params[:image])
      @address.addressable = @location
      @address.save
      @locations = Location.all_as_select_options
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render layout: false }
      end
    else
      render :update
    end
  end
end

def edit
  @address = @location.address
end

def update
  @location.image ||= Image.new
  @location.address ||= Address.new
  address = params[:address]

  if @location.update_attributes(params[:location]) &&   @location.address.update_attributes(address) && @location.image.update_from_uploaded_data(params[:image])
    flash[:notice] = 'Daten für den Ort wurden geändert.'
    redirect_to location_path(@location)
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Die Daten konnten nicht gespeichert werden'
    render action: 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @location.destroy if @location.owner.id == current_user.id
  redirect_to action: 'index', controller: 'locations'
end

private

def load_location
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end
```

Rspec:

```
describe 'request to edit' do
      before do
        login(mock_admin)
        @location = create_location
        @image = create_image
        Location.stub!(:find).and_return(@location)
        Image.stub!(:find).and_return(@image)
        @location.image = @image
        get :edit, id: @location.id
      end
      it 'should be successfull' do
        response.should be_success
      end
      it 'should load the requested location' do
        assigns(:location).should eql(@location)
      end
      it 'should load the locations address' do
        assigns(:address).should eql(@location.address)
      end
    end
```

My attempt: Allowing parameters like location and image in my edit method. Like it was suggested at [Can't update my nested model form for has_one association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984093/cant-update-my-nested-model-form-for-has-one-association)

I tried the

```
'params.require(:...).permit(...)'
```

and

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for(:..., update_only: true)
```

solution which were suggested. But even with all parameters allowing it didn't work out. Do you know why though? I tried to modify the methods but o well...

Edit -- -- Model:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :owner, class_name: '::User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_one     :address, as: :addressable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one     :image, as: :visualisable
  has_many    :events

  validates_presence_of :owner_id, :name

  def display_name
    [name.to_s, address&.display].compact.join(', ')
  end

  def self.all_as_select_options
    all.collect { |m| [m.name, m.id] }
  end

  def can_be_deleted_by?(user)
    owner == user && events.count == 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to delete the image?
Because `Failed to remove the existing associated image.` says so.

If so, try to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for(:..., allow_destroy: true)` to your `Location` model.

Comment: Thank youfor your response! I tried to add 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for(:image, allow_destroy: true) but somehow it didn't work out. Yes, I try to delete it. I know I have to use the allow_destroy somewhere but I get even more error when I put it in the model.

Comment: Can you attach content of your `Location` model to the question?

Comment: And what exact error do you get when you adding 'allow_destroy'?
Do you also adding `:_destroy` parameter in `params.require` like so:


```params.require(:location).permit(some_location_params, image_attributes: [:file, :_destroy])```

Comment: Added my model. I just get more error from my tests. Like, my create function isn't working anymore then as well. I didn't add :_destroy parameter. Gotta try it now. Really, thanks your your time and support!